Unable to access external expansion drive (HDD)
My external expansion drive is a Seagate HDD. When I click on the external drive's icon in the left-hand menu, Ubuntu displays the following message:
Unable to access "Expansion Drive"  Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at/media/allan/ Expansion Drive6: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
My Ubuntu version is 24.04.1 LTS.
I am able to access the external drive fine in Windows, which is installed on a separate drive to the one I have Ubuntu installed on, hence the external drive appears to still be working. I was able to access the external drive in Ubuntu very recently, i.e. earlier on the same day, and made no changes to Ubuntu before it failed to access the external drive.

So if Windows can access it, it is NTFS? And Windows normally uses fast startup which sets hibernation flag. That prevents Linux NTFS driver from accessing NTFS partitions to prevent loss of data when hiber file is restored. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

@oldfred 9 I don't know whether the external drive uses NTFS. I originally did use it with Windows, before switching to Ubuntu, but I've been using that same drive with Ubuntu for years since then. Only yesterday did Ubuntu cease being able to access it. The same would apply for the hibernation flag.

Windows turns fast startup back on with some updates. Or it could need chkdsk, which you only can run from Windows. You need to know format. sudo parted -l
